# Is it possible to have the Integrated terminal *always* on the right?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you open VS Code, the terminal defaults to opening on the bottom. You can click on the icon to move it to the right. I'm wondering if there's a way to set opening on the right as the default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - introduced in v1.20 there is the setting `workbench.panel.defaultLocation` with the option of "bottom" or "right".